# Help me solving this riddle

Tags: logical-deduction

4 people were imprisoned in different cages without any food or water. It is possible to get out of the top, but:

- Above the first cage there is a big flame.
- Above the second cage there is a huge and heavy stone.
- Above the third there is permanently boiling water.
- The cage number 4 is locked over top and bottom.

Moreover, all these locked cages hang over a deep ocean. Nearby there is a boat that you can reach by swimming. Those in the first 3 cages can escape through the bottom but they can't swim, while the fourth person can. By the way, the person in cage 3 can open the fourth cage because the key is in his cage.

> You need to find a solution to save the lives of four prisoners.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I took the liberty of formatting your puzzle to make it easier to digest. If you feel that this detracts from the puzzle, you can always click 'edit' under your puzzle and roll back the changes. While you are waiting for responses, you can take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), which will give you your first badge.

Comment: Is it possible to get out from the bottom?

Answer (score 4):

> The person in cage 3 can open cage No. 4. The 4th person will escape through bottom and as he is able to swim to the boat he will be saved. Now he can bring the boat below the cages 1, 2, 3 and the rest of prisoners who are non-swimmers can directly get in boat without swimming through the bottom door and hence all four will be saved.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I edited your answer with the spoiler mark-up, so people won't get spoiled.